# return a text value when conditions are met in excel

Tags: excel

A value is entered in cell B3. I have entered 200 in cell C3. I have entered 400 in cell D3.

Now in cell E3 I want to show that the value in B3 is less than C3 with the word Low or if B3 is between the values in C3 and D3 with the word OK or if the value in B3 is more than D3 with the word High.

As an example, I enter 100 in B3. I want E3 to show the word Low. If I enter 250 in B3 I want E3 to show the word OK and if I enter 450 in B3 I want to show the word High.

How would I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 3):

The `IF(condition, valueIfTrue, valueIfFalse)` command is what you want here, but you'll need to use it in a few stages.

*(in cell E3)*

```
=IF(B3<C3, "Low", IF(B3>D3, "High", "OK"))
```